# How to fix Unity collision problem with 2D sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I've made this game right here: https://youtu.be/OxJEeOTldcM

And I'm facing an issue with the maze wall's colliders where, in certain levels (not just the one I'm showing in the video below), the ball goes through the walls when it's being forced against the wall by the movement.
Here you can see what I'm talking about: https://youtu.be/dVU3LWKuXJ0

I've already dealt with this and compromised by making the maze's rotation speed a lot slower than I initially intended to. I wanted the maze to rotate as fast as the player's movement, but that made the ball go through every single wall.

So the way I'm creating these levels is this: I have these pre-made PNG mazes, I import them into the level and I apply a Polygon Collider 2D on them. But it seems like that Polygon Collider alone can not properly deal with my game's collisions.

More than this, I started layering some empty game objects with box colliders on some of these walls, trying to make them stronger. This does work, but it's still not enough, and the ball keeps going through some of them.

The ball, as well as the walls, have rigidbodys on them, and I've set their Collision Detection to Continuous, based on some answers I've seen online regarding bad collision detection. Still doesn't fix it.

I've also tried making those maze's walls thicker in Photoshop, but I can't go thicker than they're right now without ruining the space the ball should be moving in, as well as distorting the maze's look.

There has to be a way in which I can fix this bad collisions of Unity. I need the ball to stop going through walls, as this is obviously an essential part of my game.
I also want to be able to set the maze's rotation back to being as fast as the player's movement, without having to limit its speed, but honestly I'd be happy if I can just fix this collision problem with the current speed.

Comment: Can you show us your inspector for both the ball, and the maze?  can you also show us how you are rotating the maze and moving the ball?

Comment: @AresCaelum Sure. This is my maze inspector: https://imgur.com/zGOhDAW
This is the ball's inspector: https://imgur.com/XuLLxqn
And this is the script I'm using to rotate the maze: https://imgur.com/nhbg9Ti
The ball's movement is just gravity from the rigidbody.

Comment: Have you attempted to use the builtin physics systems for rotating your object?  Currently, you have 2 rigidbodies, and you are manually adjusting the rotation in a normal update instead of a fixed update,  These is causing issues with your physic interactions and making the ball go through the wall

Comment: @AresCaelum Just setting the Update function to FixedUpdated instead solved this issue. Thanks a lot for pointing it out! I'm also able to speed up the maze's rotation.
I tried marking your answer as correct, but I think it has to be posted as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Yea it has to be an answer, I didn't write one because I was trying to troubleshoot the issue, however Erik Overflow has a pretty good write up on the physics interactions, and the differences between Update and FixedUpdate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most frequent cause of "clipping through walls" is not bad collisions. It's usually due to poor understanding of Unity's separation of Physics and Frames.

Unity calculates collisions and physics on a fixed update cycle, and generates frames on a dynamic update cycle based on CPU resources. These are often explicitly leveraged by FixedUpdate() and Update() in Monobehaviours.

Everything in Unity happens on one of these 2 cycles. Frame based logic like changes to a transform happen on the dynamic update cycle, and physics logic like collisions happen on the fixed udpate cycle.

You are likely rotating your puzzle using the transform. This rotation to the transform happens outside of any physics calculation, and if you rotate fast enough you can end up clipping through walls before the physics calculation has a chance to run and generate a collision. This is very noticeable when you have very high FPS (like the uncapped FPS of the inspector). However, locking your FPS only masks the issue, and the bug can still occur.

To fix your issue, I implore you to make your rotation changes to the Rigidbody2D itself instead. Something like this should work:

```
public class SimpleRotation: MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rigidBody2D;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(rotateRight)
            rigidBody2D.rotation += 1.0f;
        if(rotateLeft)
            rigidBody2D.rotation -= 1.0f;
    }
}
```

Something else important to note is that Unity only updates input on the frame, so if you read your input during the FixedUpdate(), you may double read your input (or miss it completely). It is a good idea to read your input on the Update() cycle, and set a variable to transfer logic between the methods.